# Using add_action before add_filter on a plugin?

Tags: plugins, actions, filters

I'm writing a plugin and having a problem. I have `add_action('publish_post', 'sender');` and I want this function to run first before the add_filter function, although it won't. Is there a way to do this? I've tried moving the add_filter below add_action but that doesn't work. Also pasting the add_filter one into the add_action function doesn't work. Thanks for the help.

Edit:
For example, if this would work it would be great.

```
  if (add_action('publish_post', 'sender'))
  {
      add_filter('wp_insert_post_data','changePost','99',2);
  }
```

But it doesn't and somehow still runs the add_filter function first.

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense. add_action and add_filter both just your functions to the hooks to the system, they don't control the order in which hooks are called.

Comment: in the normal publishing flow `wp_insert_post_data` is fired by WordPress before `publish_post` so I'm not sure thats the way to go, what are you trying to do, maybe we can think of another way

Comment: Take a look at the `has_action()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter the order in which you call `add_action()` and `add_filter()`.

What matters is the order in which the corresponding `do_action()` and `apply_filters()` are called.

So, if `apply_filters('wp_insert_post_data')` is run before `do_action('save_post')`, tough luck. You'll have to think of another way to achieve the desired result.